# Can we use the verb 'own' in the progressive tense?

Tags: word-usage, progressive-aspect

> "As a result, cell phones are now commonplace, **with** at least 85
>   percent of adults in the U.S and the U.K **owning** one."

Can we use the verb 'own' in the progressive tense? What is the rule behind this? And what does 'with' mean here? Does it mean 'which have/has'?

*Source: Focus on Vocabulary 1. Chapter 9*

Comment: As an aside, *progressive* is an aspect, not tense. :)

Answer (score 4):

> As a result, cell phones are now commonplace, with **at least 85 percent of adults in the U.S and the U.K owning one**.

The Original Poster asks if we can use *own* in progressive ('continuous') constructions. Good question. The answer is no, not usually. The reason for this is that *owning* something describes a situation or state and not an action. We call verbs like *OWN* stative verbs. We don't like to use stative verbs in progressive constructions in English:

- *I am owning a car. (wrong)

However, the clause in the Original Poster's example is not a progressive construction. There is no tensed verb in the clause and there is no auxiliary verb *BE* before the *-ing* form.

The preposition *with* cannot take tensed clauses as a Complement. The verb *owning* here is a non-finite, tenseless form of the verb, called a *gerund-participle*.

The preposition *with* often has a similar meaning to *have* . Here, however, it just shows that the two clauses are both true at the same time, and offers the 85% as evidence for the fact that cell phones are now commonplace.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You meant because of 'with' we use 'own' in the participle form. like I am interested in reading books.?

Comment: @MickeyMouse Yes, that's right. :)